# I am getting "Error" countdowns in my EggTimer code. It's supposed to be counting down the time each egg takes

Tags: ios, swift, countdowntimer, iboutlet, ibaction

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let eggTimes = ["Soft": 5, "Medium": 7, "Hard" : 12]

    
    @IBOutlet weak var eggCountdown2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eggCountDown: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eggCountdown3: UILabel!
    
    var count1 = 7
    var count2 = 5
    var count3 = 12

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
      

        var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(UIMenuController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func update() {
        switch UILabel() {
        case eggCountDown:
            print("\(count1) seconds to get your medium egg")
                    count1 -= 1
        case eggCountdown2 :
            print("\(count2) seconds to get your soft egg")
                    count2 -= 1
        case eggCountdown3 :
            print("\(count3) seconds to get your fucking hard egg")
                    count3 -= 1
        default:
            print ("Error")
            
        
        }
    }
    
    

    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let hardness = sender.currentTitle!
        
        print(eggTimes [hardness]!)

    }
}
```

I am getting "Error" countdowns in my EggTimer code. It's supposed to be counting down the time each egg takes. I have tried multiple ways to tackle this but always ended with up this. Also I have been scraping Apple documentation for the same but still cannot find the relevant answer.

Screen shot:

[image: Screenshot of my main.storyboard]

Comment: When editing, please take care to not override previous edits.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than switching on an unrelated label – which cannot work – create a property for the hardness

```
var hardness = ""
```

and one counter is sufficient as you apparently not going to run two timers simultaneously.

```
var counter = 0
```

and assign both values in `hardnessSelected`

```
@IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.hardness = sender.currentTitle!
    self.counter = eggtimes[hardness]!
    print(counter)
}
```

Then switch this way

```
@objc func update() {
    switch hardness {
    case "Medium":
        print("\(count1) seconds to get your medium egg")
                counter -= 1
    case "Soft" :
        print("\(count2) seconds to get your soft egg")
                counter -= 1
    case "Hard" :
        print("\(count3) seconds to get your fucking hard egg")
                counter -= 1
    default:
        print ("Error")
        
    
    }
}
```

And you need to check when the countdown ends and to start the timer in the `IBAction`. And to avoid bad cooking experience set the repeat interval to 60 (one minute) or multiply the egg times by 300.